# Node JS POST method with authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find anything in the docs on exactly how to do this.

http://nodejs.org/api.html#request-method-149

I need to make a Node js POST with authorization something similar to this in ruby:

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
    req.basic_auth 'jack', 'pass'
```

I am trying to essentially do this:

```
var client = http.createClient(80, 'http://api.foo.com');
  var rq = client.request('POST', '/path/', 
  {
    'authorization' : [account, password]
    'key': value,
    etc....
  }
```

Comment: wow, viewed over 1000 times and never upvoted ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just encode the string `account:password` in base64 using a `Buffer` and set it has header with the key `Authorization`, prefixed with the word `Basic`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for us more ignorant (Improvements can be made!). Works for twitter's streaming API. Listen for response and then data, as per usual when making requests.

```
var hackClient = http.createClient(80, 'stream.twitter.com');
var request = hackClient.request("GET", '/1/statuses/filter.json?'+querystring.stringify(params),{
    "Host":"stream.twitter.com",
    "Authorization":"Basic " + new Buffer('user' + ":" + 'pass').toString('base64'),
    "User-Agent": "Twitter-Node"
});
request.on('response', function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        stream.receive(chunk); //example usage, no stream object in this example exists
    });
    response.on('error', function(error) {
        stream.emit('error', error); //again, for example
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        stream.emit('end');
    });
});
request.on('error', function(error) {
    stream.emit('error', error);
});
```